# Hide Loading Data, Once Page has loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web

Been asking a lot of jquery questions lately, I'm trying my best to learn a lot about it.

Anyway, I am sending an Ajax HTTP request to a PHP page in order to make a login form without requiring a page refresh. Now since it may take some time to connect the database and get the login information etc..

Now I do have loading as a .html but how can I hide the loading data once data has loaded?

Tried to use a few functions but didn't seem to work.

Thanks so far, this site has helped me a lot through the learning process.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Make a function that returns the data, then call it whenever you
    // need the current values
    function getData() {
        return {
            user_login: $('#user_login').val(),
            pass_login: $('#pass_login').val()

        }
    }


        function loading(e) {
        $('#content').html('Loading Data');
    }

    function check(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({

            url: 'ajax/check.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: getData(), // get current values
            success: function (data) {
                            $('#content').hide('slow');

                alert(9);

            }

        });

    }

    // Don't repeat so much; use the same function for both handlers
    $('#field').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var username = $('#user_login').val();

        loading(e);
        check(e);

        }
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
        loading(e);
        check(e);
        } 


    });

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/login.js"></script>
                <div id="content"> Loading...</div>

                <div id="field">
            <input type='text' name='user_login' id='user_login' placeholder='eg: Mark@gmail.com'> <br>
            <input type='password' name='pass_login' id='pass_login'> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
            </div>
```

Comment: What is happening in your script?

Comment: Basically it going to send a request to ajax/check.php.
I am making A login form with ajax, so it doesn't refresh the page.

Now loading(e) will call the Loading... Function but I Want it to call the .hide once the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function check(){
    $.ajax({

        url: 'ajax/check.php',
        type: 'post',
        error: function(){
           alert('An error has occured.');
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#content').show('slow').html('Loading');
            //loading(e);
        },
        data: {user_login: $('#user_login').val(),pass_login: $('#pass_login').val()}, // get current values
        success: function (data) {
                        $('#content').hide('slow');

            alert(9);

        }

   });
}

$('#submit').click(function(){
   check();
});

$('#field, #field input').keyup(function(e){
        var username = $('#user_login').val();
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        check();
        } 
});
```

Markup

```
    <div id="field">
        <input type='text' name='user_login' id='user_login' placeholder='eg:Mark@gmail.com'> <br>
        <input type='password' name='pass_login' id='pass_login'> <br>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
```

Good luck!!!

Comment: You cant use a submit type button for an ajax call. if you do, then you must return false after click event. The check function does not require an event e parameter inside. Your code was unnecessarily bulky

Comment: I know it was.

My first real Java Script/JQuery Application. Im better when I'm coding with PHP.

Anyway. I Found the problem. I forgot to re-include the JQuery CDN(could host it myself on my local machine)  and the login.js files.

Thanks alot ;.)

SF is helping me though in learning JQ.

Comment: On stackoverflow, you show your appreciation by accepting an answer by clicking up arrow and checking the answer as accepted. People will only answer your future questions if you show some appreciation.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up.
I gave giving you the appreciation with the tick.

I need 15 reputation to click arrow up but I have clicked the tick.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'm not sure if your code will return a success. This code will help you find out if the response is not successfully. If you get a browser alert. It means you have a server side error. Its either the url path is wrong or your server response statuscode is 500 (Internal error).

```
$.ajax({

        url: 'ajax/check.php',
        type: 'post',
        error: function(){
           alert('An error has occured.');
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#content').show('slow').html('Loading');
            //loading(e);
        },
        data: getData(), // get current values
        success: function (data) {
                        $('#content').hide('slow');

            alert(9);

        }

});
```

Refactoring your code entirely will look like this. Choose first or second:

```
$.ajax({

        url: 'ajax/check.php',
        type: 'post',
        error: function(){
           alert('An error has occured.');
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#content').show('slow').html('Loading');
            //loading(e);
        },
        data: {user_login: $('#user_login').val(),pass_login: $('#pass_login').val()}, // get current values
        success: function (data) {
                        $('#content').hide('slow');

            alert(9);

        }

});
```

Comment: its on the right track but I want it to start saying loading once the user clicks the button or hits enter.
Sort of like how Facebook register form works for example.
When it loads the file it will hide loading.

Comment: The code above simply says: beforeSend, show loading......after the loading is sent and complete, hide loading. beforeSend is triggered when you click or press enter and success is triggered after loading therefore the loader hides. your code is too long for a thing like this. I'll reconstruct it if u want.

Comment: Show your html markup. i need to see your submit button. Is the page refreshing on click? If yes, your button markup is wrong. use <button></button> or <input type="button"> button

Comment: Heres the login markup/form.
Its going to ajax when enter is pressed(keycode==13) or when the button is pressed.
I updated the OP. Look at the top of the page for the HTML markup/form.

So once its get the login data and check.php has been executed fully I want it to hide the load.

Comment: change <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">   to    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">

Comment: Above codes do not appear to work.

Might give up. Harder then I though lol

Thanks for trying.

Comment: try dude. did u see my second answer. check your css also

Comment: Ok I got it working :.)
Would you have a email or other contact? Since i'm new to the community I only have 6 reputation. 

Might have a few more question and the thread is getting long.

Comment: chukwu@metrodroid.com. find me on my social network for programmers. www.metrodroid.com. subscribe and follow me!!!! You'll get constant feeds from me on ur mail and fb page.you can also post snippets and grow. Like i said, its a social network for programmers.Stackoverflow is often times for intermediate professionals, not starters!!!!

Comment: Ok. I have joined the site, So far The site looks great. I am good with PHP Programming as ive been going with PHP on and off for around 2-3 years. Ive just started expanding onto other programming languages to expand my knowledge.

Thanks again.

Comment: Always contact me via my mail chukwu@metrodroid.com. The site is barely 1week old. If you need any tutorial on a particular technology. start a forum on that topic or leave me a mail. welcome to metrodroid. Lets communicate via mail. Stackoverflow might get pissed. lol